# What are best ways to perform File Database Input Output Operation

Tags: c#, database, file, input

My application is developed to take input from text/excel files, do validations and then perform database operations. Similarily it also takes input data from database and write it into text file/excel files. I am currently using stream reader and writer class from system.io namespace for input/output from text files, but I believe there are other options available in current frameworks which will give better performance compare to approach I am currently using. I like to know what are other approaches we can use to perform such activities. Share some link for books or tutorial available for it.

Comment: If there is a simple solution, why your making it a complex by using such tools? What you describe may seems like a simple one, as long as your not doing very complex operations on DB or files. So give more information.

Comment: Thinking from performance point of view. Currently no. of incomding transactions in my system is in lacks which will go up to milions in months. Also not find any way to use stream reader for excel files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is typically referred to as [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) which is short for Extract, transform, and load.

The default ETL tool for the C# programmer is [SQL Server Integration Services or SSIS](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/solutions-technologies/business-intelligence/integration-services.aspx) because of its .NET integration. You should note that it doesn't require that either the targets or sources have SQL Database involved it just acts as the broker.

[CSV Reader](http://www.csvreader.com/) is a C# only solution that comes at a fairly reasonable price. This means that the context of doing the ETL is in your application. If you're writing an application where a user picks a file and loads it manually this is nice option. If you need automation you'll have to write a Windows Service or use a scheduler.

In the Open Source Space there's [Rhino ETL](https://github.com/ayende/rhino-etl)

Comment: Please tell me best solution which comes with dot net framework itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to use gembox to perform I/O in excel files:
http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/overview

For text files I believe the system.io is the best aproach...